# Can a form be invoked on a click event in AngularJS ?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am creating a project to put into practice what I have learned about AngularJS. I created a form, which uses a controller. In the form, I have a button to save the information filled in by the user. After the information is save into the database I would like to call a second form to continue, (this form has its own controller) etc. How can I do that ?

Comment: please add your code example to the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not navigating to a different view, you probably dont need another controller. You can show and hide forms conditionally with ng-if. Ie. say first form is done, you've posted it to the database. You can do something like this

```
$scope.form = 1

<form id="form1" ng-if="form === 1">
//your form html
</form>

<form id="form2" ng-if="form === 2">
//your form html
</form>
```

then when form1 is submitted, you can do

```
$scope.form = 2
```

in your controller to hide the first form and render the second one

If you're set on the different forms having different controllers, you can do something like this

```
<div controller="mainCtrl">

<form controller="form1Ctrl" id="form1" ng-if="form === 1">
    //your form html
    </form>

    <form controller="form2Ctrl" id="form2" ng-if="form === 2">
    //your form html
    </form>
</div>
```

You would set the form variable from the mainCtrl's scope

Comment: Thank you ceckenrode. I have done something similar to your solution in the past. I will see how to adapt it to this problem. Thank you for your time and suggestion.

Comment: I implemented this option and it worked. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-submit` for this:

```
<form ng-submit="goToNextForm()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="email">
    <button type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.goToNextForm = function(){

   //code to save data and move to next controller/form here

}
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul Arora for your time. I will try your solution.